# Writing a text file in new format

Tags: text-files, file-writing

I have a text file like this:

```
   1 0.1278000E-01  0.000000      0.000000         
 259 0.1172645E-01-0.5057909E-02  0.000000         
 260 0.7262609E-02-0.1052830E-01  0.000000
```

It has 4 columns and 3 rows. The numbers in the last column are always zero. If the number in the third column is not zero (row 2,3) this number is attached to the number in the second column.
I want to add something to this file and change its format to:

```
Point(1) = {0.1174800E-01, 0, 0};

Point(259) = {0.1172645E-01, -0.5057909E-02, 0};

Point(260) = {0.7262609E-02, -0.1052830E-01, 0};
```

Does anybody know how I can do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What programming language are you using?  or where are you doing this?

Comment: I am using it because I want to convert the text file that I get from ANSYS to the format readable for GMSH. These are coordinate of some points and I want to export to GMSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this problem in Python 3.6:

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('input.txt')]
output = open('output.txt', 'w')

for line in lines:
    line = line.split()
    if len(line) == 3:
         line[1], line[2] = line[1][:line[1].find("E") + 4], 
                                    line[1][line[1].find("E") + 4:]
    output.write('Point({}) = {{{}, {}, 0}};\n'.format(line[0], line[1], line[2] 
                                                        if float(line[2]) != 0 else '0'))

output.close()
```

EDIT: It's a bit hard coded now that the values are not separated by spaces, but it works fine. I think you could improve it with regex, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks. It works somehow but if you look at the output.txt there is no "," between the second and third column ! In addition what if I have for example 100 lines instead of only 3 lines in this example? How can I expand it to 100 lines? Thanks again.

Comment: I realized it does not separate the second and third column correctly and adds one more "0" column to the end. Anyway the output is different from what I want.

Comment: You said that the input has 4 columns so I assumed that the lack of separation between the second and third column was a typo in your question. Otherwise, you don't actually have 4 columns but 3 with one that combines two.

Comment: As for the last 0, isn't the last column of each line always 0? It is what you said in the second sentence. Is there a scenario where it's not 0?

Comment: Yes I do have 4 columns. the number "-0.5057909E-02" in the second row and the number "-0.1052830E-01" in the third row should be separated from the previous number. The output file that I have mentioned in my question shows what exactly I need. In addition I want to implement it to many lines like 100 lines. I was wondering if you could help me with that as well. Thanks!

Comment: To answer your previous question, yes it can scale to 100 lines, you don't need to change anything the code is already dynamic and scales to any number of lines because of the for loop :)

Comment: Wait so there is a space in the intput col2,3 but the output does not separate the col2,3 with a comma? Is that what's happening for you?

Comment: For the first row there is 2 spaces between column 2,3 but for the rest of the rows (2,3) there is not any space between row 2,3 as you can see in the my question.

Comment: For example for the second row it gives back: Point(259) = {0.1172645E-01-0.5057909E-02, 0, 0}; but I need :Point(259) = {0.1172645E-01, -0.5057909E-02, 0};

Comment: Why are the second and third line inconsistent with the first one? Can we assume that every negative value in col 3 will be concatenated to the col 2 or is that just the case for those 2 rows?

Comment: It only happens to the first row. You can forget about the first row. I can fix it manually. All of the rows are in the same style as rows 2,3.

Comment: I edited it so it works with non separated values, it's hard coded to split exactly 4 characters after the first E (the exponent followed by the - and two digits), let me know it that causes a problem.